# FME - how to sort data in verses

Tags: line, fme-form, sorting

I have many elements in my layer. In the table, I have measure - distance and curvature. These two data in columns are connected with each other. For example (first verse):
0 - 35;
4420 - 35;
4157 - 30

As you can see these numbers are mixed.
How can I sort data in the distance column from the min to the max? Keeping in mind the connection between two columns.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to put the attribute into a list, where there is a specific sort tool. A list is basically FME's way of having a single attribute with multiple values.

In this case:

- Use an AttributeSplitter transformer to turn the distance column into a list.

  - Use a comma as the delimiter character
- Use a ListSorter transformer to sort the contents of the list
- Use a ListConcatenator transformer to turn the list back into a comma-separated attribute

I don't think there are any issues with the sorting, though I'm not 100% sure if this affects the curvature column or not. Would that need to be sorted in the same order? That would complicate things somewhat.